# Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Tags: java, jdbc

```
String query = "insert into dept values(?,'?','?'))";
PreparedStatement pu=con.prepareStatement(query);
pu.setInt(1, 2);
pu.setString(2, "a");
pu.setString(3, "ss");
pu.execute(query);
```

Comment: care to ask a question?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the quotes around the question marks.

Answer (score 2):

The single quotes are around your placeholder characters are causing this error. Remove them:

```
String query = "insert into dept values(?,?,?))";
```

Comment: They are worse than unnecessary: they are the cause of the problem.